# How to call a model without validation?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have recently been using FASTAPI and Pydantic.

I would like to know the path to use to create a pydantic model without any validation.

I could see that there was the `construct()` method, however, this method still calls the personal validation methods created using `@validator`

Example of my code:

```
class Feedback(BaseModel):
    rating: int
    comment: str
    date: datetime.date

    @validator('rating')
    def rating_validator(cls, rating):
        if rating > 5 or rating < 0:
            raise ValueError('value is not a valid rating')
        return rating

    @validator('date')
    def date_validator(cls, date):
        if date != datetime.date.today():
            raise ValueError('value is not a valid date')
        return date
```

In this example, the date validator allows when creating a feedback, checked if the date corresponds to that of the day, but when I want to return this value, later, when it comes from my DB, the validation necessarily leads to the error since it is to return to a different day.

So, I would like to succeed in using this model, without the validation.

Comment: You should use 2 models. 1 for application input, 1 for full model coming from the database.

Comment: There is no other method to avoid code duplication ?

Comment: There will be no duplication; you move all the fields to a common parent model, and only add your validators to the input class that inherits from the parent model.